# Rails production log level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `rails 4.2.6`. And the `log_level` is `:warn` for production environment. But when I `tail -f` the production log file on server I am seeing that it logs at `:info` level. So the log file is getting bigger in a short time. I am really creazy. Is there any clue that how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the application is running in production environment? Fire up the rails console and execute `Rails.env` and see what it prints. Check  what log_level is set in environments/production.rb and make sure it is not being overridden.

Comment: Make sure you restart the rails server after changing config options.

Comment: Exactly it is production. From console it says that the log_level is :warn. But it does not act like that.

Comment: @SeanHuber I restarted it so many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. The solution is this: `config.action_view.logger = nil`.